# how to add non-linear gradient to svg shape

Tags: svg

I would like to add a gradient to SVG shapes that is related to the square root, rather than linear. I have only come across linear, and radial gradients in documentation. Is there a way to define the function that applies the gradient to the shapes?

Comment: What you've found is all there is. You could fake it with lots of stops on a linear gradient.